# R shiny checkboxGroup to plot data on map

Tags: r, shiny, r-leaflet

I am very new to shiny, and I have a question.
I have a simple dataset with observations (Number_Total) of species (Species), in a certain location (X,Y).

I would like to generate a map, that enables you to select the species in a dropdown menu. Shiny then shows you were the species occurs on the map.

I got pretty far (for my experience), but selecting species in the menu does not do anything...

```
ui <- (fluidPage(titlePanel("Species Checker"),  
                 sidebarLayout(
                   sidebarPanel(
                      selectizeInput('species', 'Choose species', 
                   choices    = df$Species, multiple = TRUE)
                     ),
                   mainPanel(
                     leafletOutput("CountryMap", 
               width = 1000, height = 500))
                 )
))
```

The server side

```
server <- function(input, output, session){
  output$CountryMap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% 
      setView(lng = 10, lat = 40, zoom = 5) %>%
      addCircles(lng = df$Y, lat = df$X, weight = 10, 
      radius =sqrt(df$Number_Total)*15000, popup = df$Species)
  })


  observeEvent(input$species, {

    if(input$species != "")
    {
      leafletProxy("CountryMap") %>% clearShapes()
      index = which(df$Species == input$species)
      leafletProxy("CountryMap")%>% addCircles(lng = df$X[index], 
      lat = df$Y[index],
                                               weight = 1, 
     radius =sqrt(df$Number_Total[index])*30, popup = df$Species[index])
    }
  }) 

}
```

And finally plot it

```
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I know my code is probably messy, but again, I blaim my experience =)
I did not manage to get an example dataset in here right away, so here it comes as picture
[image]

This is the result of the above code (with slightly different  data)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGZxm.png)

Comment: The code above results in this:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you need. I think you are skilled enough to understand this but comment if you have any questions.

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # map_data <- reactive({
    # req(input$species)
    # df[df$Species %in% input$species, ]
  # })

  output$CountryMap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% 
      setView(lng = 10, lat = 40, zoom = 5)
  })

  map_proxy <- leafletProxy("CountryMap")

  observe({
    md <- df[df$Species %in% input$species, ]
    map_proxy %>%
      addCircles(lng = md$Y, lat = md$X, weight = 10, 
      radius = sqrt(md$Number_Total)*15000, popup = md$Species)
  })
}
```

Comment: Aha yes, that's a great help indeed! I understand the code.
Now I can select species, that will be shown on my map. 
If I deselect a species, that species remains plotted on my map.

I have been trying to figure it out, but not succesfull so far :-)
I'll give an update soon :-)

Yet again, thanks!

Comment: Consider marking it correct if it solved your problem.

Comment: Hm, well, I am still struggling to 'reset' the map. I'll comment below :-)
Soon solved I hope :-)

Comment: okay, I have edited the answer and commented out `req(input$species)` in `map_data` reactive. This should solve your problem. Let me know.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not change?
The species that are plotted, remain plotted...

I am sorry, and yet again, Thanks!

Comment: Try the new edit. Share the output of `dput(head(df))` i.e. your input data so that I can test and fix the solution myself.

Comment: Ah yes, indeed, the new edits have done the job! Great! Thank you very much for your efforts, appreciated!