# R shiny: deselect from selectize

Tags: r

First of all, my thanks to Shree, who cleaned and made my previous code more performant [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53186213/r-shiny-checkboxgroup-to-plot-data-on-map)

Anyhow, I have some code that enables a user to select one or more species (from selectizeInput). The application shows you the species distribution on the map.

Now, I am puzzled, because I cannot deselect species? Once distributions are plotted, they remain on the map and I cannot remove them anymore...
I have been looking thoroughly, but unable to see it.. I am pretty new to shiny.. so probably an easy mistake?

All code below,
THanks!!!
JOnas

DATAFRAME

```
df<- data.frame(
  Number_Total = sample(c("5", "6", "1", "3")),
  Species = sample(c("Ilione trifaria", "Pherbellia argyrotarsis", 
"Euthycera seguyi", "Ilione trifaria")),
  X= sample(c("37", "28", "21", "30")),
  Y= sample(c("-5", "-16", "-10", "-15"))
)
```

UI

```
ui <- (fluidPage(titlePanel("Species Checker"),  
                 sidebarLayout(
                   sidebarPanel(
                      selectizeInput('species', 'Choose species', 
choices = df$Species, multiple = TRUE, 
options = list(placeholder = 'select species'))
                     ),
                   mainPanel(
                     leafletOutput("CountryMap", width = 600, height = 600))
                 )
))
```

SERVER

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  map_data <- reactive({
    #req(input$species)
    df[df$Species %in% input$species, ]
  })

  output$CountryMap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% 
      setView(lng = 20, lat = 40, zoom = 2)
  })

  map_proxy <- leafletProxy("CountryMap")

  observe({
    md <- map_data()
    map_proxy %>%
      addCircles(lng = md$Y, lat = md$X, weight = 10, 
                 radius = sqrt(md$Number_Total)*15000, popup = md$Species)
  })
}
```

Run the application

```
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: are you sure the Code is working? For me it crashes as the Long/lat values seem to be of type character and not numeric?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below (I've unquoted some of the variables in `df` as otherwise the app crashes):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

df <- data.frame(
  Number_Total = sample(c(5, 6, 1, 3)),
  Species = sample(c("Ilione trifaria", "Pherbellia argyrotarsis", 
                     "Euthycera seguyi", "Ilione trifaria")),
  X= sample(c(37, 28, 21, 30)),
  Y= sample(c(-5, -16, -10, -15))
)

ui <- (fluidPage(titlePanel("Species Checker"),  
                 sidebarLayout(
                   sidebarPanel(
                     selectizeInput('species', 'Choose species', 
                                    choices = df$Species, multiple = TRUE, 
                                    options = list(placeholder = 'select species'))
                   ),
                   mainPanel(
                     leafletOutput("CountryMap", width = 600, height = 600))
                 )
))

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  map_data <- reactive({
    #req(input$species)
    df[df$Species %in% input$species, ]
  })

  output$CountryMap <- renderLeaflet({

    leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% 
      setView(lng = 20, lat = 40, zoom = 2) %>%
      addCircles(lng = map_data() %>% pull(Y), lat = map_data() %>% pull(X), weight = 10, 
                 radius = sqrt(map_data() %>% pull(Number_Total))*15000, 
                 popup = map_data() %>% pull(Species))

    })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

You need to pull the values directly from the `reactive` context; I'd also suggest to do this in one statement rather than spreading it around.

P.S. In case your initial dataframe actually does contain all the variables in `character` format, you can add just in case the `mutate_at` statement in `map_data` part, like this:

```
map_data <- reactive({
    #req(input$species)
    df[df$Species %in% input$species, ] %>%
      mutate_at(vars(c("Number_Total", "X", "Y")), funs(as.numeric))
```

Then the script functions also with your initial dataframe provided here without manual changes.

Comment: Hello, it works!
Thank you for providing feedback! Very much appreciated!